# want to give placeholder 2 different colors

Tags: html, css, placeholder

Is there any trick I can make a placeholder 2 different colors, 
here is the code

```
<input type="text" 
       class="form-control setting-form" 
       id="inputDefault2" 
       placeholder="http://blabbr.im/#itsmynewawesomechat">
```

I want to give "blabbr.im/" color rgba(255,255,255,0.3)
and "#itsmynewawesomechat" color rgba(255,255,255,1)...

Comment: or is there any way we can use the placeholder and value for the same input ... like placeholder (no-editable) and value (editable)...

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to style a placeholder with two different colors. As an alternative, you could style both `<label>` and `<input>` to look like a single `<input>` (or any other tag like a `<span>`).

```css
label, input {
    background-color: #4679BD;
    border: 1px solid #567890;
    float: left;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    padding: 2px 5px;
}

label {
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    border-right: 0;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    padding-right: 0;
}

input {
    border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
    border-left: 0;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

:-moz-placeholder {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

::-moz-placeholder {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label for="hashtag">http://blabbr.im/</label>
    <input id="hashtag" type="text" placeholder="#itsmynewawesomechat"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

to change placeholder style you can use:

```
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: red;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: red;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: red;  
}
```

you can use the id or nth-child() to target your second input

Comment: No, I want to give different colors to the same placeholder ... I want to give "blabbr.im/" color rgba(255,255,255,0.3) and "#itsmynewawesomechat" color rgba(255,255,255,1)...